# jekyll _config.yml edited but nothing changed?

Tags: jekyll

following a tutorial and edited and pushed my changes. It shows the changes correctly in the repository but nothing changes on the web page.

```
https://github.com/StephanBKetterer/StephanBKetterer.github.io
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some errors in your _config.yml :

The first broke your last two builds as seen [here](https://github.com/StephanBKetterer/StephanBKetterer.github.io/commits/master) and certainly in your config panel.

```
author:
  ...
  github           :"StephanBKetterer"
```

Must be :

```
author:
  ...
  github           : "StephanBKetterer"
```

Always one space after colon.

The second emits a warning :

> Defaults: An invalid front-matter default set was found: blah blah

```
defaults:
...
  #_pages
  - scope:
      path: ""
      type: pages
      values:
        layout: single
        author_profile: true
```

Must be indented like this:

```
defaults:
...
  #_pages
  - scope:
      path: ""
      type: pages
    values:
      layout: single
      author_profile: true
```